# iOS SDK - How to know which kit, class to use?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to iOS development and was wanting to know how to efficiently locate which kit, class to use to achieve certain things.

For example, I'm planning to build an app that heavily makes use of calendar events and I found that I should be looking at using something like `eventkit` to build upon but it's not clear for me within this kit which class to instantiate and which method to use in what order.

Can someone please direct me to a place where I can see some code examples of using a range of different kits?

Comment: Have you tried a google (or whatever your favorite engine is) search? "eventkit example" leads to Apples [Calendar and Reminders Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) pretty quickly. From there you are one click away from Apples [SimpleEKDemo](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleEKDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010160) project.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch Thanks. I did some search but haven't come across that example. Maybe it's not eventkit that I'm looking for because what I want to achieve is having a custom weekly calendar within my app. If you don't mind giving me some heads up, what kit should I look for if that's the case?

Comment: Check Apple sample codes.They are categorized  by Frameworks https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code

Comment: @adnan Thanks for sharing. Maybe I didn't look hard enough as I didn't notice there were sample codes section there..

Answer (score 1):

I think you can learn things as you described from 'Reference'.

Two ways to check Apple Official References in Xcode. One is clicking the function name, parameter or those colorful keywords while you pushing the 'option'. The second way is using three fingers to touch those "keywords" slightly on the touchPad.

Or you can check many kits references by visiting iOS Developer Library (website). I'm also new to iOS Development, I wish things I said can help you.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I learned those Xcode tips through some video tutorials, but my main issue as a beginner is that I just don't know which function to start with as I'm new to everything about iOS development. I guess I should just check out as many examples as I can to see how things are done.